# Assembly.LoadFrom("Newtonsoft.Json.dll") could not load file

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, .net-5

my launcher application (.NET5) uses Assembly.LoadFrom("totoPlugin.dll") to load and run a plugin "toto".

The "totoPlugin" depends on `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, so I'd like the launcher to load the Newtonsoft.Json.dll as well. But when the launcher execute the

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("Newtonsoft.Json.dll")
```

then it crashed

[image]

my actual workaround is to install the Newtonsoft nuget in the launcher project.. so that the plugin toto would work. But it is not a good solution.

- Do you know what happened? why couldn't we load the Newtonsoft assembly? The path is correct, `Assembly.LoadForm` detected the version of the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, it just could not "LoadFrom" it, and the error message is not very helpful.
  [image]
- what is a good way for my launcher application to be able to load an assembly (plugin) which depends on other assembly?

Comment: "Do you know what happened?" -> is the file there (in the bin folder where your app runs)? If it's not there, why do you expect this to work? If it is there, is it the right file (correct version, etc)?

Comment: any error? tried absolute path?

Comment: .NET Core or .NET Framework? The assembly resolution process is quite different

Comment: .NET 5 (net core)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/collect-details